# Changing the Currency via code in c#

Tags: c#

I am using the following to display an amount:

String.Format("{0:C}", item.Amount)

This display  £9.99

which is okay, but what if I want the application to be able to control the currency and to be able to change the currency to day

$9.99

How do I change the currency format via code

Comment: Don't forget that you need to store the prices separately, or allow for (changeable over time) rates of exchange as well -- otherwise, I'll be ordering in USD to a GBP credit card :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the culture in the call to `Format`:

```
    decimal value = 123.45M;
    CultureInfo us = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
    string s = string.Format(us, "{0:C}", value);
```

Answer (score 18):

The currency symbol is defined by CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol. The property is read/write but you will probably get an exception if you try to change it, because NumberFormatInfo.IsReadOnly will be true...

Alternatively, you could format the number by explicitly using a specific NumberFormatInfo :

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
nfi.CurrencySymbol = "$";
String.Format(nfi, "{0:C}", item.Amount);
```

Comment: this cloning is very slow, almost 280ms in this example

Answer (score 2):

```
CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID);
info.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "EUR";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;

Console.WriteLine (String.Format ("{0:C}", 45M));
```

or

```
NumberFormatInfo info = new NumberFormatInfo ();
info.CurrencySymbol = "EUR";

Console.WriteLine (String.Format (info, "{0:C}", 45M));
```

Comment: That's right, you should not change the thread's current culture, especially not by simply changing the currency symbol. Use CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("culture string") to get the appropriate culture information (along with all formatting settings).

Answer (score -1):

If you change the displayed currency of an amount, then you are changing its unit of measurement too. £1 <> €1 <> $1. Are you absolutely *sure* of the business requirement here?

Comment: It sounds a pretty common requirement for an app running on a corporate desk to show values in multiple currencies...

Comment: Yes I understand your point, this setting is being used link a TimeZone setting and is for the complete application not individual cases

Comment: It's not like formatting dates and times. Even if you just want one user-configurable default currency for the whole app, it does not excuse you from the task of converting all the amounts on the fly from one currency to another.

Comment: Also, if you have a stored value in currency X and you display it as currency Y, not only do you have to access some kind of currency-conversion service to display the new value, but you also have to make it clear to the end user that the amount is an estimate.