# Currency format from currency symbol

Tags: c#

I do have values and currency symbols in my database (BRL, USD and etc) and would like use that to write a formatted string, something like:

```
int number = 100;
string currencySymbol = "USD";
string formattedNumber = number.ToString("C", currencySymbol);
```

I've tried to cast currencySymbol to cultureInfo but it is not possible as written in this post [get CultureInfo from a Currency Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230705/get-cultureinfo-from-a-currency-code)

Comment: The accepted answer from the post you link is correct.  I'm not sure how this question is different.

Comment: what does _"it is not possible"_ mean?

Comment: Do you want the output to be `100.00 USD` or `$100.00`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the Currency via code in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017139/changing-the-currency-via-code-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I have USD and would like the output to be $ @DStanley .

Comment: How many currencies are you talking about?  You may be OK building a static dictionary to translate.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking to use custom currency symbols in formatting. You can do:

```
int number = 100;
var numberFormatInfo = (NumberFormatInfo) NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
numberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol = "USD";
string formattedNumber = number.ToString("C", numberFormatInfo);
```

A better approach would be to store different culture information ("en-US") in database and then retrieve the culture based on it and use its predefined currency symbol. But it will not be same as yours. In case of US, it is `$` and not `USD`.

Comment: Same solution is provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1017169/3242721) so I really believe this thread is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Habib. Have you worked in multi-currency systems? Would you know if storing CultureInfo is a common way of making that? For instance, how would amazon organize there prices to be able to sell them for many countries?

Comment: @EduardoCucharro, I have some experience, but I don't know how amazon does it. It is not just as simple as displaying values for different cultures, It is how the information is stored. The simplest way would be store culture info/ or get them at client side for each user and then format the output according to that culture, that can be used for currency as well as dates.

Comment: It also depends on how you are going to manage the accounts, Do you want to store everything in USD, or in local currency , do you have to consider using a service for exchange rates, etc.